# mysqli_fetch_array stop / multiple usage

Tags: php, mysqli

I tried to use mysqli_fetch_array twice in a code, and it seems not to work.

```
<?php 
$i=1; 
while ($i < $x)
{     
while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($result))   
  {     
   echo $i;
   echo $data['ID'];   
  }    
}    

while {$i > $x)
{     
 while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($result))   
 {     
  echo $i; 
  echo $data['ID2']    
 }    
}    
?>
```

This doesn't work for the second case. Why? Is there any way to get my idea to work?
I want to use some of the array values in one place, and some in another

Comment: What about using an array?

Comment: it contains a number like "10"...could be any number, its just for display purposes here...

Comment: @YourCommonSense what do you mean?

Comment: you second while `{` contains this and how can both the conditions will be true for same value???

Comment: no, lets say x is 10, then $i 1-9 will be first while, and 10-.... will be second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you fetch all rows the pointer is at the end of the result set and you cannot fetch more.  You need to reset it to the first row before attempting to fetch from it again:

```
mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);
```

Alternately, the first time through assign rows to an array and use that later:

```
while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {     
   $rows[] = $data;   
}    

foreach($rows as $row) {
    //whatever
}
```

Depending on what you are doing not a great way to split up rows, but based on your comments (you have to increment your counter):

```
$i=1; 
while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($result) && $i < 11) {     
   echo $data['ID'];   
   $i++;
}    

while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($result) && $i < 21) {     
   echo $data['ID2'];
   $i++;    
}
```

Comment: but the rows that used in first while should not used AGAIN in second, the second should only use the REST of the first fetch.

Comment: Your `while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($result))` is fetching ALL rows until `$data === false` which is when there are no rows left.

Comment: and with your solution i can use foreach twice?

Comment: Yes.  Once you store the rows in an array each foreach will start at the begining of the array.

Comment: But that is not what i want. Eg. $data contains 30 rows, then the idea is to `while($i < 10)` the FIRST 10 rows get used, and in a second while, `while($i > 10)` the REST 20 rows will be used. Not start again at row 2, continue at row 11!

Answer (score 0):

Where are you resetting the vars, also you should do the while loop like this:

```
while ( ($i < $x) || ($data=mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) )
```